# Excel values gotten from a formula cannot calculate in SUM

Tags: excel

This one is a little long winded, but basically in my Excel sheet, there is a main form which users enter a series of data in the horizontal axis.

```
| Sampling Qty | 4/125 | 6/125 | 5/125 |
```

Next the Excel is required to split the data into 2 separate columns to be shown in another sheet as a report.

So I transposed the data in another sheet:

```
=TRANSPOSE(DATA!L170:CC170)
```

And on the same sheet used these formula to get the separate data:

```
=IF(ISERROR(LEFT(I2,FIND("/",I2)-1)),"", (LEFT(I2,FIND("/",I2)-1)))

and

=IF(ISERROR(MID(I2,FIND("/",I2)+1,LEN(I2)-FIND("/",I2))), "", (MID(I2,FIND("/",I2)+1,LEN(I2)-FIND("/",I2))))
```

Giving me this:

```
| 4/125 | 4 | 125 |
| 6/125 | 6 | 125 |
| 5/125 | 5 | 125 |
```

Then on the report sheet, I simply use a formula to reference the split data.

```
=Sheet1!L2
```

Once all data is copied, it needs to be calculated into sum

```
=SUM(H8:H57)
```

But for some reason, the value is not showing up. I made sure to check the cell format and it is in fact set as number.

Each cell with the formula referencing Sheet1 has a green arrow on the top-left of the cell which says formula is unprotected. So I did that but still the sum won't calculate...

At this point, I'm not sure what is the main problem. Anyone knows?

Comment: MID returns text that only looks like a number; It has no numerical value. Use a **double unary** to convert the text to a true number.

Answer (score 2):

LEFT and MID returns text that only looks like a number; It has no numerical value. Use a **double unary** (aka *double minus*) prefix to convert the text to a true number.

```
=IFERROR(--LEFT(I2, FIND("/",I2)-1), "")
```

and

```
=IFERROR(--MID(I2, FIND("/", I2)+1, LEN(I2)), "")
```

The IFERROR function can effectively cut your IF(ISERROR(... formulas in half.

Comment: Well, they're both two characters but yours is three keystrokes (shift is needed to produce the asterisk). I've also seen `+0` used; any valid mathematical operation forces the conversion.

Comment: I find it is only two keystrokes when using the number keys section on the right hand side of my keyboard...

Comment: You're right of course. It's been ages since I've used a 101 keyboard.

Comment: Works fine in newer Excel versions, but doesn't want to work in 2003. Is double unary supported there?

Comment: No, the `--` is fine but IFERROR wasn't introduced until xl2010.